# Customize login page IBM BPM portal

Tags: portal, ibm-bpm, login-page

I am trying to change the look and feel of the IBM BPM portal's login page. I read about it in [this](http://wiki.bpmwiki.com/display/commwiki/Customizing+BPM+8.0+Process+Portal+using+WebDAV) link. I have installed the windows hotfix suggested in the link and i have also checked 'Default to basic authentication when certificate authentication for the HTTPS client fails' in Websphere application server but still i am facing an error when i am trying to upload files into the WebDAV folder using Cyberduck. It just gives a message saying 'bad request'.I can browse and see all the files and folders but I just can't upload. I can upload using cyberduck in my friend's PC without installing the hotfix or checking the authentication option in websphere application server. So now i am sure that the problem is in my BPM or my operating system. Me and my friend are using Windows 7 and the same BPM version. I am trying to find the solution for this since 3 days on google but no luck. Someone please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using the WAS administrator to connect. It seems like a privileges issues. Switch to Admin ID and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Customization of IBM BPM login page is needed admin authorization for example your tw_admin to connect to it using cyberduck , note: if you install fix pack your customization will be lost and restore the old login page.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use the Deployment Manager password to alter contents through CyberDuck.